# Derivative of Determinant Map

Tags: linear-algebra

For $ V= ( V_1, V_2) $  and $ W= ( W_1, W_2) $, given a determinant map $ \det : \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $ \det (V,W)=  V_1W_2-V_2W_1$. Then have to find the derivative of the determinant map at $( V, W)\in R^2$ evaluated at $(H,K)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ .

Please help me with this terminology.

It seems to me if $ U= V_1W_2-V_2W_1$, 
then derivative of $U  =  V_1W_2-V_2W_1$. (by using the Jacobian technique)
Then, in that case

derivative of U at $(H, K) = \det (H, K)$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write $U((V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2)) = V_1 W_2-V_2 W_1$. Then just compute the partial derivatives: $\frac{\partial U(V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2)}{\partial V_1} = W_2$, $\frac{\partial U(V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2)}{\partial V_2} = -W_1$, $\frac{\partial U(V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2)}{\partial W_1} = - V_2$, $\frac{\partial U(V_1,V_2,W_1,W_2)}{\partial W_2} = V_1$. Then the derivative at $(V,W)$ in the direction $(H,K)$ is
given by
$$DU((V,W))((H,K)) = W_2 H_1-W_1 H_2-V_2 K_1+V_1 K_2 = \det(H,W)+\det(V,K)$$

This can also be written in terms of the Frobenius inner product as

$$DU((V,W))((H,K)) =\langle \begin{bmatrix} W_2 & -V_2 \\ -W_1 & V_1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} H_1 & K_1 \\ H_2 & K_2 \end{bmatrix} \rangle$$

and so we can write the gradient
$$ \nabla U((V,W)) = \begin{bmatrix} W_2 & -V_2 \\ -W_1 & V_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you please explain to me, how did you evaluate the derivative of determinant along $(H, K)$? what is the formula? Thank you.

Comment: The formula is on the last line of the answer?

Comment: Thanks. but can tell me the intuition behind the formula. why it works and what is it? It looks like some sort of inner product of some vectors to me.

Comment: I think my answer has a bug.

Comment: ok. can you please edit it? Thank you.

Comment: It is after midnight here. The bottom part of the answer (after note) is correct. The derivative I gave is incorrect. Not sure how it lasted all this time.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. No problem. Whenever it is possible please edit it. Thank you :).

Comment: @GA316: I corrected my answer, not sure what I was thinking before. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @GA316: Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: What you've called the "Frobenius inner product" is different from [Wikipedia's](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Frobenius_inner_product) definition. They claim $\langle AB\rangle=\text{trace}(A^*B)$, while yours appears to be $\langle AB\rangle=\text{trace}[\text{adjug}(A^*)B]$, where $\text{adjug}$ denotes the [adjugate](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Adjugate_matrix).

Comment: Can you comment at all on the difference between these inner products and why the latter appears here, rather than the one on Wikipedia?

Comment: @WillG I am not sure what you mean. I am using the standard inner product corresponding to the Frobenius norm, $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (A^*B)$. The derivative of the determinant map is $D \det (A) H = \operatorname{tr} ( \operatorname{adj} (A)H) = \langle \operatorname{adj} (A)^*, H \rangle$, all of which is consistent with the above and usual usage.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok I see now. I misunderstood your second to last line.